# How to write Latex

Tags: pdftex

I am a new user of latex and I am trying to learn it. Now, I am writing my STATEMENT OF PURPOSE, so, I have written a format in latex. But, I don't know how to write the name "Name: XYZ" without any gap in starting. [image]

Comment: Please show us a minimal example code.

Comment: How is that different from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/521417/194703 ?

Comment: Yes, this is my question and I just used                                                                    \begin{document}                                                                                                                                    Name: XYZ

Comment: You need `\noindent`, e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent Name: XYZ
\end{document}`. However this is really not the way of writing such statements of purpose. Rather, if you provide a complete document, people will be see what you have tried and provide you with a good solution.